# flutter dependences version solving failed

Tags: flutter

I am facing this error. I really want to use both packages but I can't figure out how to solve the next error. Can you help me?

```
Because u_lo_musico_v3 depends on awesome_calendar ^1.1.3 which depends on intl ^0.17.0, intl ^0.17.0 is required.
So, because u_lo_musico_v3 depends on intl ^0.18.0, version solving failed.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you could do.

- Downgrade the version of intl library that you are using to version `0.17.0` as awesome_calendar is not compatible with what is in your pubspec `0.18.0`.
- You could add `intl ^0.17.0` under dependency overrides. Which overrides all versions of intl that whatever dependency may use and resolves it to `0.17.0`